# How do I select an object from a list generated by another method?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When my form is loaded, a query is run to get all employee records from SQL.  Dapper compiles everything, and I put the contents in a List.  My DataGridView table is bound to that list.  I have a click event that retrieves the EmployeeID from the first column.  Now, how do I sort through the List for the EmployeeModel with the matching ID without repeating the query?  I will use this to bind other listboxes with the properties of that EmployeeModel.  My first thought was to make the Form_Load method public and have it return employeeList, but it's an async method, and I don't know how to handle that.  Would that be the right approach?  Is the answer altogether different?

EDIT: I just noticed the first two lines are copied and pasted from my inventory initialization.  They should read:

```
        var employeeList = await InitializeEmployeeList();
        EmployeeGridView.DataSource = employeeList;
```

```
       public async void Dash_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
       {
           var inventoryList = await InitializeInventoryList();
           InventoryGridView.DataSource = inventoryList;

           //Initialize Employee List
         
           var employeeList = await InitializeEmployeeList();
           EmployeeGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
           EmployeeGridView.ColumnCount=9;
           EmployeeGridView.AutoSize = true;
           EmployeeGridView.DataSource = employeeList;
           EmployeeGridView.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Employee ID";
           EmployeeGridView.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "ID";
           EmployeeGridView.Columns[1].HeaderText = "First Name";
           EmployeeGridView.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "FirstName";
           EmployeeGridView.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Last Name";
           EmployeeGridView.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "LastName";
           EmployeeGridView.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Nickname";
           EmployeeGridView.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "Nickname";
           EmployeeGridView.Columns[4].HeaderText = "JobTitle";
           EmployeeGridView.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "JobTitle";
           EmployeeGridView.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Forklift";
           EmployeeGridView.Columns[5].DataPropertyName = "ForkliftCert";
           EmployeeGridView.Columns[6].HeaderText = "AWP";
           EmployeeGridView.Columns[6].DataPropertyName = "AWPCert";
           EmployeeGridView.Columns[7].HeaderText = "Confined Space";
           EmployeeGridView.Columns[7].DataPropertyName = "ConfinedSpaceCert";
           EmployeeGridView.Columns[8].HeaderText = "NFPA51b";
           EmployeeGridView.Columns[8].DataPropertyName = "NFPA51bCert";

       }
```

```
        {
            DataGridViewCell selectedEmployeeCell = EmployeeGridView.CurrentCell;
            int selectedEmployeeRow = selectedEmployeeCell.RowIndex;
            string selectedEmployeeID = EmployeeGridView.Rows[selectedEmployeeRow].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put a global

```
 public static InvertoryList lst;
```

after getting data from your method
fill it with your data

```
if(lst==null)lst=new InvertoryList();
lst=your inventoryList;
```

then you can reach **lst** from everywhere in your form.